# How to Search within SMSes in Hangouts App?

Tags: sms, google-hangouts

The default messaging app on Android provides the search feature, which allow users to search within SMSes. But I wasn't able to find Search in hangouts app. (as I have Sms integration with hangouts, I need to search within SMSes on some occasions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to do a search within Hangouts from the app.  Google, the king of search, still hasn’t added this most basic of features.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the best way to search through my SMSes is to switch app temporarily. You can go back to Hangouts afterwards.

Lets hope Google realizes this is a needed feature for Hangouts.